# Hold button down, increase label integer every second , how do in Android?

Tags: android, button, timer, count

How do I get a label to increase an integer label every 5 seconds a button is held down. I tried to do it with a timer function. I feel like I'm close here. Currently this just increases it by every press. If I put the increase counter part in the timer brackets it crashes the app. Please check out the following:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    Timer t = new Timer();
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            count=count+1;
                           //app crashes if i insert the code here
                        }
                    }, 5000);

                    level= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
                    level.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354356/how-do-i-add-a-number-to-an-integer-every-second) helped me up to this point but it crashes the app this way!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `UI` elements can only be changed from the `UiThread`.Use your classname in place of `YOURCLASSNAME`.

```
  Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            count=count+1;

            YOURCLASSNAME.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    level= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
                    level.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler or TimerTask(with runOnUiThread()):

```
Handler handler=new Handler();  

handler.post(runnable);  
Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){  
  @Override  
    public void run() {  
      //increment variable here.
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);  
     }  
 };
```